# Not receiving any email notification for my post or comment

Tags: support, user-accounts, notifications, email

I asked a question at Ask Ubuntu. A user posted an answer and comment. But I did not receive any email notification of the response.

In preferences, I have email id set, Inbox emails and Other emails checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emails are not sent as soon as someone posts an answer or comments.

Emails in Stack Exchange websites are more like digests.

The way they work is, if you don't check your notification messages (The ones in the top left, where it says `StackExchange) for a certain amount of time (depending on your preferences), you get an email saying:

> 1 new item in your Stack Exchange inbox

Of course it's not always 1, it's just as many items as there are in your inbox.

Comment: but i never get any emails, there were answers and comments of 2 to 5 hours elapse time. every time i had to check manually to see weather i got an update or not. i meant my gmail email! you posted since 2 hour and i had to manually check for ur response, no email at my gmail!

Comment: @Bsienn In your preferences, the least you can choose for ` Email me my unread inbox messages` is 3 hours. So 2 hours wasn't enough to send you the email. You keep manually checking for responses, there is a high chance you won't get an email, well like you said, you are checking for responses, so no need to send an email. *Hopefully you won't see this comment before 3 hours so you get the email*

Comment: hehehe, Thanks for ur time. I get it :) though the setting were set to daily, i had misunderstanding of that portion.